# How to connect MongoDB with PowerShell?

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I already tried with the following code:

```cs
$mongoDbDriverPath = '
 C:\Mongodb\net45\'
$mongoServer = 'localhost:27017'

Add-Type -Path "$($mongoDbDriverPath)MongoDB.Bson.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$($mongoDbDriverPath)MongoDB.Driver.dll"
$databaseName = "test"
$collectionName = "sample"
$client = New-Object -TypeName MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient -ArgumentList "mongodb://localhost:27017"
$server = $client.GetServer()
$database = $server.GetDatabase($databaseName)
$collection = $database.GetCollection($collectionName)
Write-Host $server,$database,$collection
$query = [MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query]::EQ("Name", "sample")

$results = $collection.Find($query)
$results
```

but it shows some errors:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation,Version=4.0.0.0,`Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
>   At D:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\Mongodb With Powershell\task1.ps1:8 char:11

How do I overcome this error?

Comment: Make sure you use a version of PowerShell that runs on the .NET 4.0 CLR (PowerShell 3.0 or newer). Post the output from `$PSVersionTable` to your question

Comment: PSVersion : 5.0.10586.962
CLRVersion :  4.0.30319.42000

I am using above mentioned version powershell

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I know I am little late but I have been playing around with Mongodb and Powershell for the last couple days. The easiest solution that I have found is to install the MongoDB cmdlets from the Powershell gallary:

https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc

Step 1: Get and install.

Mdbc is distributed as the PowerShell Gallery module Mdbc. In
PowerShell 5.0 or with PowerShellGet you can install it by this
command:

```
Install-Module Mdbc
```

Step 2: In a PowerShell command prompt import the module:

```
Import-Module Mdbc
```

Step 3: Take a look at help:

```
help about_Mdbc 
help Connect-Mdbc -full
```

Then go through the following steps to see if the setup is working:

```
# Load the module
Import-Module Mdbc

# Connect the new collection test.test
Connect-Mdbc . test test -NewCollection

# Add some test data
@{_id=1; value=42}, @{_id=2; value=3.14} | Add-MdbcData

# Get all data as custom objects and show them in a table
Get-MdbcData -As PS | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String

# Query a document by _id using a query expression
$data = Get-MdbcData (New-MdbcQuery _id -EQ 1)
$data

# Update the document, set the 'value' to 100
$data._id | Update-MdbcData (New-MdbcUpdate -Set @{value = 100})

# Query the document using a simple _id query
Get-MdbcData $data._id

# Remove the document
$data._id | Remove-MdbcData

# Count remaining documents, 1 is expected
Get-MdbcData -Count
```

Comment: How to retrieve data using mongo db queries using this Mdbc module?

Comment: How to add Json formatted data to Add-MdbcData? Or is there a better way? banging my head against the wall to add new documents with json.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr:

So you just need to find this assembly and add it to the same folder as the MongoDriver. I found it by created a console app in visual studio and added the driver from Nuget. The interop assembly will be in the packages directory.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/2.5.0/

Research:

Enable Fusion Logging as outlined here:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Now initialize the MongoClient

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Mongo\MongoDB.Bson.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\Mongo\MongoDB.Driver.dll"
$mongoClient = New-Object MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient
```

You should see something like like in the fusion logs:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (12/29/2017 @ 1:50:26 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = powershell.exe
Calling assembly : MongoDB.Driver.Core, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Publisher policy file is not found.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Temp/Mongo/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Temp/Mongo/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Temp/Mongo/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Temp/Mongo/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

So based on the error, it's loading the assembly `MongoDB.Driver.Core` and that is where the exception is being thrown.

[image: Reflected Mongo Assembly]
So you just need to find this assembly and add it to the same folder as the MongoDriver. I found it by created a console app in visual studio and added the driver from Nuget. The interop assembly will be in the packages directory.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/2.5.0/