# Load data to Azure Cosmos DB (Mongo API)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Not able to write data to Azure Cosmos DB (Mongo API) by using below PowerShell script. I want to see $output data in Cosmos DB (Mongo API).

```
$Params = @{
 "URI" = 'https://3ea5e53b-817e-4c41-ae0b-c5afc1610f4e-bluemix.cloudant.com/test/_all_docs?include_docs=true'
}

$output = Invoke-RestMethod @Params | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 11
```

Comment: I haven't found any docs to explain how to use power shell script to insert documents into cosmosdb mongoapi, and what I can find is [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/powershell-samples-mongodb), and including the samples it referred, they all stopped before manage collections. So my idea is you may need to create api to achieve inserting action and use power shell call the api to finish the inserting action. And if you don't know how to create an api to insert into cosmosdb, you can add comment which programing language u'd like to use and one may offer a sample

Comment: If there is any API or SDK then I prefer to go with Python or C#

Comment: I googled this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-on-cosmosdb-using/) for c# sdk on crud.

Comment: Thanks Tiny. Not sure what is their source. In my case I am trying to read data from URI

Comment: Hi there! Note that you asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66249449/how-to-write-data-in-azure-cosmos-db-mongo-api-storage-programmatically) yesterday. And as I already responded in the comments before you deleted it, you should look at available MongoDB-specific PowerShell cmdlets. I even provided [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45010964/272109) to a very-closely-related question.

Comment: Hi, somehow that question was closed by Stack Overflow saying didn't meet their guidelines. Because of that I deleted there and created new one. 
I am not able to achieve using cmdlets.

Comment: @DineshMadhup - I'm not quite sure what you're asking, then. Your code example is in PowerShell; is there a reason why cmdlets don't work for you? Note that `Invoke-RestMethod` is a cmdlet as well. Also, to be clear: in general, when using the MongoDB API, the approach would be the same as interacting with a native MongoDB endpoint, from a wire-protocol perspective. It's not the same as interacting with the native SQL API of Cosmos DB.

Comment: in my case $output contains JSON document and I want to pass the JSON document in Azure Cosmos DB (Mongo API). From link you referenced, I don't see how can I write to Azure Cosmos DB collection.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I followed the link you have referred. But my target is Cosmos DB for Mongo API. Would you be able to specify any specific cmdlet for Cosmos DB for Mongo API?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write to Cosmos DB's MongoDB API using PowerShell. You need to use one of the [MongoDB Drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/) to read and write to Cosmos DB.